# JPA Error: detached entity passed to persist when attempting to persist multiple duplicated instances

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I've got two **OneToMany** relations between an entity and two lists of objects and one **ManyToOne** relation between the same entity and another entity as better explained below:

1. Entity `VehicleRent` has one or many `Car` (a list of `Car`) and one
   or many `Bike` (a list of `Bike`);
2. Entities `VehicleRent` belong to one `User`.

When persisting (em.persist()) `VehicleRent` for the first time, it all goes well. However, when I try to persist a new, but different `VehicleRent` afterwards it keeps overwriting the first one.

Also, when I try to duplicate an existing instance of `VehicleRent` it returns the following error:

```
select
        nextval('rent_seq')
jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : detached entity passed to persist: poo.models.User
```

I am using the **GenerationType.SEQUENCE** for generating all classes' ids with each one having its specific SequenceGenerator (i.e. `rent_seq` for `VehicleRent`, `car_seq` for `Car` etc.).

In all relations, I am also using **CascadeType.ALL**.

Basically, I would like to persist as many `VehicleRent` instances as I would like to, regardless of them having duplicate or different attributes.

How can I achieve this behavior? I would really appreciate any help.

**Edit 1: Renting method from User.java**

```
public void Renting(List<Car> Carlist, List<Bike> Bikelist, User user) {
    VehicleRent rent = new VehicleRent(Carlist, Bikelist, user);

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(rent);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    em.close();
    emf.close();
}
```

**Edit 2: Entities (getters and setters ignored)**

**User**

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "user_seq", sequenceName = "user_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_seq")
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String nickName;
    private String password;
    private String mail;

    public User() {
    }
```

**VehicleRent**

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "rent_seq", sequenceName = "rent_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class VehicleRent{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "rent_seq")
   private long id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = Car.class)
   @JoinColumn(name = "rent_id")
   private List<Car> Carlist;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = Bike.class)
   @JoinColumn(name = "rent_id")
   private List<Bike> Bikelist;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User tenant;

public VehicleRent(List<Car> Carlist, List<Bike> Bikelist, User tenant){ 
      this();
      this.Carlist = Carlist ;
      this.Bikelist= Bikelist;
      this.tenant = tenant;
   }

   public VehicleRent() {
   }
```

**Bike**

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "bike_seq", sequenceName = "bike_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class Bike extends Vehicle{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "bike_seq")
    private long id; // I can't keep id into parent Vehicle because they'll both share the same generator (each must have their own for proper persistence).

    private int cc;
    private String type;

    public Bike() {
    }
```

**Car**

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "car_seq", sequenceName = "car_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class Car extends Vehicle {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "car_seq")
private long id; // I can't keep id into parent Vehicle because they'll both share the same generator (each must have their own for proper persistence).

private String paint;
private boolean twoDoors;

public Car() {
}
```

Comment: How are you duplicating the `VehicleRent`? When adding a new `VehicleRent` are you creating a new fresh object? If you post the entities it will be better

Comment: @Pp88 I invoke from `main.java` `user.Renting(List of <Car>, List of <Bike>, User)` two times. First goes well, second returns the mentioned error.

Comment: @Pp88 Just edited and added `Renting` method from `User.Java`

Comment: FYI variable names and method names must start lower case, anyway you are not showing us what are you passing to the method and the entities

Comment: @Pp88 Thanks for the heads up. I do intend on changing these names in the future. I've also just edited once again and added all entities (w/o getters/setters/irrelevant methods). Could you please take a look? Note: I haven't added parent abstract class `Vehicle` as I think it is not necessary for this issue's understanding. However, if you think it is, just let me know and I'll add it right away.

Comment: To be honest it looks like it is ok. Do you have any constructor in VehicleRent? If so, show it. Also add System.out.println(rent.id); before the line em.persist(rent); and check if id has expected value on first and second persist.

Comment: @ePortfel just added `VehicleRent`'s constructors. I've also added the System.out.println(rent.id) and noticed that `rent.id` is the same for both runs. It is not sequentially increasing as it should've. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be sequence problem. Not every DBMS supports this. What is your DBMS? Try @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) and check if id is generated properly. Move System.out.println(rent.id);  to the line after commit() to be sure that ids are distinct.

Comment: @ePortfel I'm using PostgreSQL v13.4 as DBMS. I've tried switching to GenerationType.AUTO but the following exceptions show up: 1. **Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory**, 2. **Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=poo.models.Car]**, 3. **The increment size of the [Car_SEQ] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].**

Comment: @ePortfel I've also moved `System.out.println(rent.id)` to the line after commit() and noticed that the id goes from 0 to 1 as expected. However, when the process is finished and it has to run `Renting` method once again for the second persistence the id is back to 0 instead of continuing the previous index (1).

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with sequences probably.

Please try this:

1. DROP sequence rent_seq in database
2. Run the version below:

```
@Entity
public class VehicleRent{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long id;
```

If you get errors with other entities (Car / car_seq), do the same for them.

It works for sure in [DataNucleus](https://www.datanucleus.org/) and [H2](https://www.h2database.com/). DBMS should create and manage sequences by itself.